# Cubic Polynomial Linearisation

Tags: linear-programming

I have a cubic polynomial defined as below which needs to be linearised as a constraint for an MIP model in Gurobipy. I have seen a couple different methods including using the Gurobi general constraint for polynomial. However, using that method makes my model infeasible. I suspect that my understanding of attributes `FuncPieces`, `FuncPieceError`,`FuncPiecesLength` and `FuncPieceRatio` is insufficient to control the behavior of Gurobi's internal process of linearising the constraint. Thus, I am looking at alternatives of explicitly linearising it using Special Orderded Sets Type 2.

The expression is defined as below:

$$ N_{cyc,m} = -12198 \cdot SOC_m^3 + 71548 \cdot SOC_m^2 - 8985 \cdot SOC_m + 2620  $$

where $N_{cyc,m}$ and $SOC_m$ are the number of charging discharging cycles and state of charge of a battery for minute $m$.

Based on the number of cycles obtained, battery degradation $Deg_{cyc,m}$ at minute $m$ is then defined as :

$$ \begin{align*}
Deg_{cyc,m} = 0.5 \cdot \left| \frac{1}{N_{cyc,m}} - \frac{1}{N_{cyc,m-1}}\right| \end{align*} $$

The formulation I have written up to use SOS type 2 is :

$$ SoC_{m}= \sum\limits_{k}\Delta_{m, k}SoC_{m, k} $$
$$ Deg_{cyc,m}= \sum\limits_{k} \Delta_{m, k} Deg_{cyc,m,k} $$
$$ \sum \limits_{k} \Delta_{m, k}=1 $$
$$ \sum\limits_{k} \delta_{m, k}=1 $$
$$ \Delta_{m, k}\leq \delta_{m, k}+ \delta_{m, k-1} $$
$$ SOC_m \epsilon (0,1) $$
$$ N_{cyc,m} \epsilon (0,52985) $$

I want to understand what is the fundamental behind choosing the right number of sets for such a polynomial and what might be the pitfalls of relative errors to the larger models.
New to this method and would really appreaciate some help.
Thank you.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurobipy